# xcode - if statement activated by a button?

Tags: xcode, button, if-statement, action

I am trying to have numbers change by different amounts, by the press of one button. I am new to xcode and do not know how to do this, any help would be nice.

I want the number to change to 15, but only when I press the button for a second time. Then, I would like, upon a third press, for the number to change 30.

```
-(IBAction)changep1:(id) sender {
p1score.text = @"5";
if (p1score.text = @"5"){

    p1score.text = @"15";
```

//Even if the above worked, I do not know how I would write the code to change it to 30.
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your example code above, you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in your `if` statement. In addition, when testing NSString equality, use the `isEqualToString:` instance method like this:

```
-(IBAction)changep1:(id)sender
{
    p1score.text = @"5";

    if ([p1score.text isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        p1score.text = @"15";
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though that the code snippet above will result in `p1score.text` always being set to a value of `@"15"` since you are setting it on the line preceding the `if` statement which makes the condition evaluate to `YES`.

To make it only change the text after the first tap you can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)changep1:(id)sender
{
    if ([p1score.text isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        p1score.text = @"15";
    }
    else
    {
        p1score.text = @"5";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if ([p1score.text isEqualToString:@"5"]){
     p1score.text = @"15";
}
```