# Xcode - How to get button to change label text multiple times

Tags: xcode, button, if-statement

I am trying to have numbers change by different amounts, by the press of one button. I am new to xcode and do not know how to do this, any help would be nice.

I want the number to change to 15, but only when I press the button for a second time. Then, I would like, upon a third press, for the number to change 30.
press 1: from "0" to "5",
press 2: from "5" to "15",
press 3: from "15" to 30", I want to learn how to add different amounts

```
-(IBAction)changep1:(id) sender {
p1score.text = @"5";
if (p1score.text = @"5"){

p1score.text = @"15";
```

//Even if the above worked, I do not know how I would write the code to change it to 30. }

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode - if statement activated by a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964180/xcode-if-statement-activated-by-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want to add a property to your view controller to store Player 1's score, something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger p1Score;
```

Then in your `init` method, you can give this property an initial value:

```
self.p1Score = 0; // you can set this to any integral value you want
```

Then, in your button tap method (`changep1`) you can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)changep1:(id)sender
{
    // add 5 (or any value you want) to p1Score
    self.p1Score = self.p1Score + 5;

    // update the display text. in code below %d is replaced with the value of self.p1Score
    p1score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.p1Score];
}
```