# Xcode - Button changing label to a series of words?

Tags: text, label, series

I want a button to change a label's text in a set series. For example, that one box app on the app store where theres a button and every time you press it, it says the next thing. I want, let's say, one button and one label. The first time you press the button, it says, "hi", you press it again and it says, "how", then, "are", "you?". How would I go about doing this? Any help would be good.

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. Are you asking how to change a label? How to connect a button to an action? This is all very basic stuff. What have you tried? Where are you having trouble? Have you read the relevant iOS documentation?

Comment: I want to change a label. I want it to change to different things from the same button. I understand how to connect the button, and I can get it to display one word, but not change to a different word from one button.

Comment: One. This is not related to Xcode. You can make iOS apps without Xcode. Two. If you can't figure out something trivial like this yourself, you should probably still be learning some algorithmic thinking instead of already developing iOS apps.

Comment: Also, please don't post the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12964180/643383) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12964719/643383). If you don't understand an answer, ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an integer property like `currentWordIndex` to your view controller to remember which is the current word.
2. Create a label. Connect it to an outlet in your view controller with a name like `wordLabel`.
3. Create a button. Hook it up to an action that changes the label to whatever text you want, like this:

```
    - (IBAction)changeTheLabel:(id)sender
    {
        NSArray *words = @[@"hi", @"how", @"are", @"you?];
        self.currentWordIndex = (self.currentWordIndex + 1) % [words count];
        self.wordLabel.text = [words objectAtIndex:self.currentWordCount];
    }
```

That is all.

Comment: +1, though it's not worth answering this (apart from getting some free rep :P)